# Render Html using RDL Local Report

Tags: rdl

I need to render html from rdl reports using the LocalReport class, I dont want to use ReportViewer for the same. Is there any way i can enable generating HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know LocalReport cannot be exported to HTML (only Excel,Word and PDF are available). But if you are still interested in export you can use following

```
Dim Report = New LocalReport
```

prepare report the same way as for viewing ([Datasource for RDL reports with ReportViewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073540/datasource-for-rdl-reports-with-reportviewer))

```
Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
Dim streamids As String() = Nothing
Dim mimeType As String = Nothing
Dim encoding As String = Nothing
Dim extension As String = Nothing
Dim bytes As Byte() = Nothing
bytes = Report.Render(RenderFormat, Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warnings)
Using fs As New IO.FileStream(RepPath, IO.FileMode.Create)
  fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
  fs.Close()
  ReDim bytes(0)
end Using
```

You can get list of available extensions with `Report.ListRenderingExtensions`

ServerReport solution is similar, but more possible export formats is available.

Comment: There are no "HTML" formats in LocalReport ListRenderingExtensions.

Comment: @Teddy: My answer starts "LocalReport cannot be exported to HTML".